# how to display axis on binary while having log scale and adding custom grid lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks

I gathered different pieces of code from here. My code looks as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f"{int(x):12b}")
data = np.arange(100)
ticks = [2, 3, 4, 13]
plt.plot(data,data)
ax.set_yticks(ticks, minor=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
plt.show()
```

So, the goal is to plot in logarithmic scale, displaying the y axis in binary and adding custom `ticks`. The code works perfectly, except that the `ticks` are displayed in decimal. As shown in the picture below. I'd like them to be also in binary. I tried to fix it, but I really have no idea how. I tried setting `ax.set_ticks([lambda x: f"{int(x):12b}"], minor=True)` but that didn't work. I'd appreciate if someone can help me.
[image: see picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the minor ticks you need `ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(...)`. You'll notice that the major and minor ticks aren't aligned equally. This is due to the tick lengths, which can be forced equal via `ax.tick_params(..., length=...)`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))
for ax in (ax1, ax2):
    ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f"{int(x):12b}")
    ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(lambda x, pos: f"{int(x):12b}")
    data = np.arange(100)
    ticks = [2, 3, 4, 13]
    ax.plot(data,data)
    ax.set_yticks(ticks, minor=True)
    ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='minor')
ax1.set_title('default tick lengths')
ax2.set_title('equal tick lengths')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', length=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that minor ticks are suppressed when their position is very close to the major ticks. Therefore, no grid lines are visible for 2 and 4. You can work around that by shifting them a bit. E.g.

```py
ticks = [2.001, 3.001, 4.001, 13.001]
```

Or you could change the role of major and minor ticks, using the `LogLocator` for the minor ticks:

```py
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(base=2))
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which='major')
```

[image: more gridlines]